Last 2 updates broke my nvidia gpu drivers, how can i prevent happening in the future?
new user here. im using 22.04 LTS, i stopped upgrading the software because lately everytime i do,  i had to reinstall the gpu driver because it boots me to a black screen with cursor, i had to bring up the terminal mode with ALT + F2 and purge the nvidia driver and reinstall. gpu is nvidia 820m and the 390 nvidia driver (since thats the lastest driver to support that gpu). the driver is not from the ubuntu repository but a patched nvidia GUI installer for kernel 6.5+ (since the driver from repository doesnt work with newer kernels). how can i keep my system upgraded without getting into that drama ?

You mention a Ubuntu release (22.04 LTS) but not which product (ie. Server? Desktop? flavor?) as they have different kernel stack defaults.  The server install defaults to GA as it doesn't change during the life of the product (ie. Servers usually prize stability) where as Desktop defaults to HWE as it changes to newer stacks from later releases; useful for newer hardware. Ubuntu flavors default to GA or HWE depending on install media.  Why not select the GA kernel stack if that's what you want; Ubuntu offers choice (the install media setting the default)

@guiverc sorry for not giving details, ive it on my laptop. i dont remember if selecting the kernel stack was even an option during the ubuntu setup. how do i check it out ?

First detail is what Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system did you install; with Desktop media for example, the kernel stack is selected at download time (via ISO downloaded), with only some Server ISOs providing choice at install time. You mention only release, not what 22.04 system (22.04 ISO/media exists with 5.15, 5.19, 6.2, 6.5 and very soon 6.8 kernels on ISO). Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server are different proudcts (Server vs Desktop) but the same release (22.04).
